# Conversion from JSON to POJO

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson-databind

```
 "testing":{"infixSuggester":{
      "Sample":{
        "numFound":10,
        "suggestions":[{
            "term":"test",
            "weight":0,
            "payload":""},
            {
            "term":",
            "weight":0,
            "payload":""}
```

I want this JSON to convert it into a POJO Class. Can anyone suggest how to do it? where "Sample" is the string value which is creating dynamically.

Comment: did you try to google it?

Comment: I tried but not able to find the answer :(

Comment: Could you plz explain what you mean by `where "Sample" is the string value which is creating dynamically. `?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-json

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Gson or Jackson can do the trick: https://stackabuse.com/how-to-convert-json-object-to-java-object-with-jackson/